# Unable to extend volume even though all prerequisites fulfilled

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I have searched for the answer to this problem for a while. I have a 64GB flash drive that I recently had to format to FAT32 to place Windows Recovery tools on it.

When I attempted to extend the re-reformatted exFAT partition to its original 64GB state with the Disk Management window, it would not allow it. I learned that Disk Management could only extend NTFS partitions.

I temporarily reformatted the disk to NTFS and [ensured the partition in question was on the right](https://superuser.com/questions/528650/how-do-i-extend-the-size-of-an-ntfs-partition), but still I am unable to extend the volume. The option remains "greyed out."

Here's a partial screenshot of the drive in Disk Management (click to zoom in):

[image]

Is there something I'm missing to extend the drive in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've reformatted it, I guess there is no more data on it. So why not delete all partitions and create a new (big) one?

Otherwise you can try alternative tools like [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/)

Comment: I more or less was hoping for an explanation as to why it was failing period, but this _is_ a valid solution. Thanks.

Comment: It's falling because Windows will not edit partition tables on non-fixed disks, natively